# How to run a code only if a Cell, not a Header, in DataGridView is doubleClicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
private void dgv_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgv.Rows) r.Visible = false;
}
```

This code works, but also works if ColumnHeaders (not only cells) is doubleClicked ?
I want to run it only if a cell is doubleClicked.
CellDoubleClick should mean CellDoubleClick and not HeaderDoubleClick.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
private void dgv_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
            if (e.RowIndex != -1) {
                //do work
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks to EveryOne. All solutions works. But, could someone maybe explain, what is then the purpose of ColumnHeaderDoubleClick handler if it runs on another handler? Seems stupid.

Comment: In your question you said that you are using CellDoubleClick. Since RowHeader is also a cell, the event fires. If you have used ColumnHeaderDoubleClick this event would only fire on column header double click. I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Cell should be Cell, Header should be Header. ThankYou, Anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could check if `e.RowIndex` is -1, which means the event happened on a header row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataGridViewCellEventArgs.RowIndex` to check if the header is clicked or any cell from the rows is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest way to do but you can achieve it like this

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (((System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)(sender)).CurrentCell != null)
    {
       //Do what you want here................
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question to @Vale on what is the purpose of ColumnHeaderDoubleClick? One example I can think of Double Click to sort the Grid by Column

Comment: Sorting is on Click, not DoubleClick. In any case, CellDoubleClick shuld be CellDoubleClick And HeaderDoubleClick should be HeaderDoubleClick. ThankYou, Anyway.